# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Surface Pro 2 WiFi Problems

Tags: 14.04, networking

So, I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Surface Pro 2. Apparently this is a problem that has been present on other devices. Whenever I attempt to use the WiFi on my device, the entire system completely freezes up. My device has a Marvell Avastar 350N wireless adapter. The same thing happened when I installed Ubuntu 15.04.